# Generalization with imbalanced classes

Tags: machine-learning, unbalanced-classes

I have a generic question about learning (binary classification) with imbalanced classes and generalization. One recipe for learning with imbalanced classes is to downsample the negatives to a ratio where the model can actually learn something. But what happens when the model is deployed on the actual, very imbalanced data? To put some numbers around this, if the positives represent 1% of the actual data, we can train the binary classifier with all the positives and an equal number of downsampled negatives. But then the model is released on data that has the actual 1:100 positive to negative ratio. Will the model still be able to find the positives? Isn't it like it was not trained on the same problem as it is used for?

Comment: It’s almost as if lying to the model leads to problems! $//$ My profile has a number of links about class imbalance, and my Data Science account recently awarded a large bounty to my question about class imbalance. It turns out to be a lot less of a problem than some people think.

Comment: Do you mean that it is not a problem in a sense that the models can be created on unbalanced datasets, or it it not a problem to have a model trained on balanced data, that is later used for use-cases with unbalanced data?

Comment: I kind of want to keep it a surprise for when you read the reference material, but statistics sees minimal problem with training on imbalanced data (except for a few edge cases, also discussed in those links).

Comment: @dave What link/doc would you recommend first?

Comment: Do you have two accounts? There’s a way to merge them. $//$ I’d start with the bountied answer to [my question on Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/126337/73930).

Comment: Dave, I knew it! :) Maybe I will read, indeed. Thank you for the insight though. I myself often train on unbalanced datasets, and what I observe is that when you balance the sets, the performance does not change (improve) drastically. So I guess that the differences in data distributions either are in the data, or they are not there, and unless the imbalance is extreme, the imbalance as such is not that much of an issue, I agree.

Comment: I stand by the first part of my first comment: `It’s almost as if lying to the model leads to problems!`

Answer (score 1):

An amazing amount has been written about this on **this site**.  It is so unfortunate that you have started a new topic on this.  The matter has been completely settled.  Class imbalance is only a problem if you use invalid analytical methods, and any attempt to change the balance represented in validly sampled data will result in a complete mess that does not apply to future non-molested samples.

One of the most important statistical principles to understand is that if the proportion of positive responses is not close to 0.5, [classification can be a bad idea](https://fharrell.com/post/classification) and what should be analyzed is **tendencies**, i.e., one should be estimating probabilities of responses.

Comment: Frank - it looks like the link to *this site* is not quite set up. I'd love to be able to access it. Can you fix the link?

Comment: To be clear, the reason I asked this question is precisely because I never liked the idea of learning a model on data that doesn't have the same distribution as the "real" data. I am not a statistician myself, but the practice of "molesting" the data is widespread in the ML community.

Comment: I clicked on the link and it’s working for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you calculate the sensitivity, and especially the specificity, you will able to detect the bias you're interested in.  For example, consider a classifier that's a shoe-box which does nothing.  Also, assume a sample size of $n=100$, and a truth table involving 5 positives and 95 negatives.  Even though the classifier does nothing, its accuracy will be 95% all the time, since it only misclassifies 5% of the positive data.  Now, as soon as you calculate the sensitivity and specificity, the resulting values will be low.

Thus, applying "diagnostic screening" using sens & spec directly sidesteps this issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can always run a validation/simulation: take your dataset, split it, use part of it that has balanced classes for training, and in the second part, if there is balance, random sample one of the classes, then perform validation. This way you will find out whether metrics (e.g., true positive rate, or false positive rate) will be the same for training as for the validation. I would guess that they will be different, but I am not a data science theoretician, so I would simply do an experiment and find out.